# procedure declarations and definitions that do not match

Tags: c, gcc

```
static void foo(void);

[.....]

void foo(void) {
    .....
}
```

yields a "foo" of static scope, whereas if "static" were moved from the declaration to the definition, you get an error.  I can't formulate a Google question that gets me to a rationale, but it does not seem rational to me....

Does anyone have insight?

Comment: `lint` would also warn here. Put `static` in both declarations.

Comment: It makes most sense to do it that way.  The question is fishing for a rationale for allowing it to be different.  I've stumbled into an environment where "static" is normally applied *only* on the declaration and not the definition.  This question came about because I was surprised to find that it was legal and made the procedure have static scope.

Answer (score 0):

Linker needs function declaration to resolve calls through translation units. So, if function is declared as static, it wouldn't be accessible outside translation unit.

If you declare functio as non-static, and define as static, you will get an error because declaration & definition don't match, but have same name.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the typical situation where the function declaration might be in a header. If you declare the function NOT static, you're telling the compiler "this function is available outside this translation unit". Then the function is defined as "visible only in this translation unit", which of course can never work.

The other way around (the way you've written it), your declaration is saying "this function is NOT available outside this unit" and the definition is "and by the way, here is the function". The fact that the definition doesn't say static is beside the point.

Admittedly, it would make more sense to force the "static-ness" to be the same between declaration and definition, but I think it still works the way it is.